# Calculate input values without NaN

Tags: javascript

As a javascript beginner I'm struggling through my code right now and can't get any further. I am supposed to divide the input of the input fields (the form has many more fields, here are only two to view). It should only be possible to enter numbers (type="number" and the result field should remain empty until all fields are filled, so no NuN. How do I proceed? If I use type="text" the calculation works correctly, but the NaN does not and vice versa.
Ideally I would like to have large numbers separated by ', so 1'000'000. Can anyone help me?

```js
let kaufpreisInput = document.getElementById("kaufpreis");
let ekInput = document.getElementById("eigenkapital");


kaufpreisInput.addEventListener("input", calculateEigenkapitalsatz);
ekInput.addEventListener("input", calculateEigenkapitalsatz);


function calculateEigenkapitalsatz() {
    let kaufpreis = parseFloat(kaufpreisInput.value);
    let eigenkapital = parseFloat(ekInput.value);

    let fremdkapital = kaufpreis - eigenkapital;


    // Check if either input field is empty or not a number (NaN)
    if (isNaN(kaufpreis) || isNaN(eigenkapital)) {
        document.getElementById("eigenkapitalsatz").value = "";
    } else {
        let eigenkapitalsatz = (eigenkapital / kaufpreis) * 100;
        document.getElementById("eigenkapitalsatz").value = `${eigenkapitalsatz.toFixed(2)}%`;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="kaufpreis" required>
<input id="eigenkapital" type="text">
<input class="nonedit" type="text" id="fremdkapital" tabindex="-1" readonly disabled>
```

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] of the issue, when you are asking a question like this - not just snippets we would still have to assemble into a working example ourselves.

Comment: Even after adding the missing closing brace for the `calculateEigenkapitalsatz` function, the provided code produces an error and not the output described.  If that's not the error you're asking about, please update the code to demonstrate the problem in the question.

Comment: There is no #eigenkapitalsatz input and it cause an error, don't know if it's a typo in the js or if there is missing html

Answer (score 0):

Fix the id mismatch ("eigenkapitalersatz" vs. "fremdkapital"). Make the inputs number inputs and the output a text input (because you're adding a '%' which isn't allowed as a number input value) or make the output a span element and set its `innerText` instead.

```js
let kaufpreisInput = document.getElementById("kaufpreis");
let ekInput = document.getElementById("eigenkapital");
let ekeOutput = document.getElementById("eigenkapitalersatz");

kaufpreisInput.addEventListener("input", calculateEigenkapitalsatz);
ekInput.addEventListener("input", calculateEigenkapitalsatz);


function calculateEigenkapitalsatz() {
    let kaufpreis = parseFloat(kaufpreisInput.value);
    let eigenkapital = parseFloat(ekInput.value);

    let fremdkapital = kaufpreis - eigenkapital;

    // Check if either input field is empty or not a number (NaN)
    if (isNaN(kaufpreis) || isNaN(eigenkapital)) {
        ekeOutput.value = "";
    } else {
        let eigenkapitalsatz = (eigenkapital / kaufpreis) * 100;
        ekeOutput.value = `${eigenkapitalsatz.toFixed(2)}%`;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="kaufpreis" type="number">
<input id="eigenkapital" type="number">
<input id="eigenkapitalersatz" type="text" readonly disabled>
```

Comment: "Make the inputs number inputs" - Why?

Comment: @MikeB So the browser can prevent invalid values. To Javascript, all input field values are still of type string